# Are there people who cheat around fog of war in Starcraft 2?

Tags: starcraft-2, cheats

Are there people who map cheat the fog of war away in Starcraft 2 on Battle.net? Do I have to worry about this?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by that? How would he take advantage of you? Plus be sure that Blizzard would fix it and temp-ban people abusing it

Comment: yeah what is a map hack and how is it different from other types of hacks? are they live editing files in their RAM or does this only work with custom homemade maps and custom games?

Comment: For anyone in the dark, to "map hack" is to cheat in such a way that you see the entire map, without the fog of war. There are supposedly ways to cheat and get SC2 to show your opponents base and units.

Answer (score 20):

Fog of war cheats ("maphacks") definitely exist.

**How to detect when you've been maphacked:**
If you suspect that you have been maphacked, load the replay. Watch the game from the perspective of your opponent. If he appears to be spending lots (abnormal amounts) of time hovering his screen over your base in the fog of war, chances are he is hacking, as in the following video.

This technique has been used to expose hackers quite a lot in the BETA phases. If you are able to detect the presence of a maphacker using this technique you can use the "report user" feature within battle.net and post an explanation in your report.

Comment: any links to articles or threads about these maphackings I would be curious to see them.

Comment: does this only work on custom maps created by the user? or do I need to worry about blizzard maps and/or ladder games having this issue?

Comment: @Ryan Maphack works anywhere.

Comment: Video in question is dead.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, map hacks have been available since early beta.

However, they aren't common, and most if not all publicly released map hacks are easily detected. There likely are unreleased map hacks that are still undetected, but it's unlikely that you'll encounter them on Battle.net.

Comment: Maphacks are common. They're rather easy to make as well. In Brood War you can maphack with a simple memory scanner. No coding required.

Answer (score 1):

BLizzard continously monitors the user's process list, so if they find anything unusual, like a memory debug/editing tool, hacked game content etc. they simply ban the user.

Comment: We all hope they will do!

Comment: I really hope they wouldn't.  As a software developer, I have tools like this running all the time!  I haven't been banned yet, thankfully.

Answer (score 0):

The problem of map hacking has been overhyped since before Starcraft 1.  I would not be seriously concerned about it.

Certainly people will accuse each other of map hacking, but these accusations have never been verified.  Like alligators in the sewers, I'll believe it when I see it.

Comment: It makes for a convenient excuse for a loss though. :)

Comment: @Torpesh that and "lag" are the most popular ones people have.  Either I have map hacks installed or everyone I play is on a 56k modem.

Comment: [Believe it.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nz164l9ogJM) For whatever reason the Blizzard forum thread in which I found this has been deleted.

Comment: @Lee so you'll notice a date on that, being August 4th.  Since then there have been a number of hacks: Map hack, Warping Immortals Hack, Spawning Zerg as a Protoss, etc.  At the time I wrote that post, none of these had been seen.  Since then.  As a result the information is dated.

Comment: Map hacking is not overhyped. In SC1 everyone was doing it all the time. I have a few friends that were alleged maphackers, I've seen it.

Answer (score -3):

According to this: http://www.teamliquid.net/forum/viewmessage.php?topic_id=140168

They are map hacks.  This is extremely sad because when they announced SC2 required battle.net to play I assume this was to prevent map hacking by hosting the game on the server.  But alas no.  Blizzard has failed.

Comment: "Failed" is pretty harsh. An un-hackable system doesn't exist. The real measure is how Blizzard responds to cheating. Can they stop it quickly? Will they ban cheaters? Et cetera.

Comment: @JavadocMD check out league of legends.  its pointless to hack because the games are hosted on the server side therefore map hacks are impossible.  (IE. they don't send you the location of units that are under the fog of war).  depending on your definition of "unhackable" I believe that LoL is unhackable

Comment: While a absolutely unhackable system may not exist, storing secret data on the server rather than the client certainly ups the effort for map hacking by a few  orders of magnitude.

Comment: That isn't an option for most games. MMOs are the exception, since you can have your code run on the server instead of the client.

Comment: @Peter - you can't do that with a lockstep synchronized RTS multiplayer system. All data has to be present on client for it to be able to perfectly predict game (thus enabling only commands to be sent between peers, minimizing network traffic and allowing minimally encoded replays). See [this article](http://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/3094/1500_archers_on_a_288_network_.php).