# What is a maphack?

Tags: starcraft-2

[There is a discussion](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4491/are-there-people-who-map-hack-in-starcraft-2) about maphacks in Starcraft2.

I understand it is a cheat. But what kind of a cheat? Or are all cheats in a real-time strategy game called maphack?

Somehow I know wallhacks and whatever, but maphack I don't.

Comment: Think of a maphack as a wallhack but for RTS

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A maphack is a cheat that reveals the whole map. You see the whole map as if you had units everywhere.

Comment: Note that a maphack would have to involve editing game executables. It's not a manually entered cheat as in the single-player mode.